# 'frmMain' does not contain a constructor thattakes '0' argument

Tags: c#

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
 public frmMain(string Uname)
 {  
   InitializeComponent();
   lblWelcome.Text = Uname;
   time.Start();
 }
}
```

Comment: private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmMain frmM = new frmMain();
            frmM.ShowDialog();
        }

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the constructor of the Form like this,

```
public frmMain()
{  
   InitializeComponent();
   ..........
}
```

or you should pass a String parameter when you create an Instance ,

```
btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   frmMain frmM = new frmMain("");
   frmM.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main method you are instantiating your frmMain (in Program.cs) like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ...
        Application.Run(new frmMain());
    }
```

But your frmMain class doesn't contain a constructor with 0 argument. Also you can change this instantiating

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ...
        Application.Run(new frmMain("strUname"));
    }
```

or add a constructor with 0 argument

```
 public frmMain()
 {  
   InitializeComponent();
   ...
 }
```